# My blogger post thumbnail looks blured on hompage

Tags: post, thumbnails, blogger

Please i have been trying so hard to fix this but to no avail,

All my post thumbnail looks blured for all kinds and sizes of images i used, even images with clear resolutions appears blured on thumbnails.

Please can someone help me with what i should do to fix this.

[My Blog Url](https://www.basenaija.com)

Comment: How can we know the problem without code or url?

Answer (score 0):

All I see is that you use tiny pictures and then resize them. Did you tried much larger (larger than your largest thumbnail size) images?